# Solve $y''+y'-2y=21e^x$ my x-coeff does not match

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $y''+y'-2y=21e^x$

I know that my attempt at finding $y_p$ should be $y_p=Axe^x$ (correct according to the book as well). But in my calculation, I find that 21=3A so A=7 correct again. But, can I ignore the fact that the coefficient in front of $x$ do indeed *not match*

[image]

(2+2A)=16 using A=7.

Comment: I think they cancel out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Differential Equation**
$$
y″ + y′ − 2y= 21 e^x
$$

**Candidate for a particular solution:**
$$
y_p=A x \, e^x
$$

**Determination of Unknown $A$:**

This implies
$$
y'_p = A e^x + A x e^x = A (1 + x) \, e^x
$$
and
$$
y''_p = A (2 + x) \, e^x
$$

Inserting $y_p$ into the differential equation gives
$$
A \, e^x \left(2 + x + 1 + x - 2x \right) = 3 A \, e^x = 21 e^x
$$
Thus $A = 7$.

**Testing the particular solution:**

$$
y_p = 7x \, e^x
$$

$$
y_p' = (7 + 7x) \, e^x
$$

$$
y_p'' = (14 + 7x) \, e^x
$$

Inserting into the D.E.:

$$
  (14 + 7 x + 7 + 7x - 14 x) \, e^x = 21 e^x
$$

which is fine.

Answer (score 2):

$$21 e^x=Ae^x(2+x)+A e^x(1+x)-2Axe^x \Rightarrow 21=2A+Ax+A+Ax-2Ax\Rightarrow 21=3A +(A+A-2A)x \Rightarrow 21=3A+0x \Rightarrow 21=3A \Rightarrow A=7$$

At the substitution you have a $'+'$ sign instead of $'-'$, which should be... So finally there is no $x$(the coefficient of $x$ is equal to $0$)